# multirobot_map_merge package not working properly

Tags: localization, multi-agent

[image]I am trying to map a Gazebo environment using 2 husky bots using the multirobot_map_merge package.

However, the merged map being produced is wrong and the robots are not being localized correctly inside the merged map.

How can I improve this? I have been trying to figure this out for quite some time now.

Comment: Probably the maps don't have common features to overlap and merge. Other reasons could be that some of your parameters are wrong or you could check that your namespaces/topic names are not the same.

Comment: The two husky bots are publishing their respective maps on /husky_1/map and /husky_2/map respectively. I have placed distinct markers (squares and spheres) to help in the localization and the map merging process.

I  am attaching the tf tree and the Gazebo world in the original post for your reference.

Comment: Did you solve the problem and which package you used?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* @بسمة احمد. I'm afraid that on StackExchange *answers* need to answer the question, we are not a discussion forum, we are a place to ask questions and get answers. If you wish to discuss a question or answer you can use [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). If you have an idea for how a question or answer can be improved, you can comment when you have [comment privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Please review [ask] and [about] for more information on how StackExchange works.